# Unnecessary cast warning in eclipse jdt compiler

Tags: java, warnings, eclipse-jdt

How to disable (suppress) unnecessary cast warning in eclipse jdt compiler without Eclipse IDE? Maybe there are any compile options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go to : -**

> Windows -> Preferences -> Java on left panel -> Compiler
>   -> Errors/Warnings.

There you can disable the warnings you don't want.

---

To disable warnings while compiling using `javac`, you can use `-Xlint:-name` flag, where `name` is the name of the warning.

See [javac doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options) for more options available while compiling.

Comment: How to do it without Eclipse IDE, maybe there are any compile options?

Comment: @Michael. Updated the post accordingly.

Comment: No, these answers were really helpful for me.

Comment: @Michael.. Yeah then its fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Err, remove the unnecessary cast?

Comment: @Michael So forget about it, or turn warnings off when compiling generated code.